# Disbable a key shortcut in Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse, binding, command, shortcut, pde

I'm struggling with a problem in the PDE environment of Eclipse. The RSE perspective configures a key shortcut as CTRL+SHIFT+A. I'm trying to disable this key shortcut when a user is working in our custom perspective. I thought I could accomplish by configuring the plugin.xml as follows:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
    <key
        commandId="my.package.Disable"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="CTRL+SHIFT+A">
    </key>
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command
        defaultHandler="my.package.handlers.DisableHandler"
        id="my.package.Disable"
        name="Disable">
    </command>
</extension>
```

For the record, the my.package.handlers.DisableHandler class contains an empty implementation. This causes Eclipse to do nothing when this shortcut is entered. The problem with this config is that the shortcut is also blocked in the RSE perspective. This is of course not something we want. Is there a nice way to disable a key shortcut for a certain perspective or are shortcuts always defined for the entire workspace?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use it, you can remove it. 
Look at http://code.google.com/p/jbaris-eclipse-plugins/source/browse/trunk/QuickSearchPlugin/src/ar/com/fluxit/quick_search/startup/StartupImpl.java